# onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type and not applicable

Tags: java, android, eclipse

New to Java, using Eclipse.
Except this error I also got some:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method onClick(View) of type new onClickListener must override or implement a supertype method

And: 
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
        Button button1;
        Button button2;
        Button button3;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            //Listeneři
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    button1.setText("Správně.");
                }
            });

            button2.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                button2.setText("COŽE!?");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `button2.setOnClickListener` method change

```
new onClickListener()
```

to

```
new OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 1):

change your button click listener to this

> button1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {}
>
> button2.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {}

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace this code
 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                button2.setText("COŽE!?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //Listeneři
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button1.setText("Správně.");
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setText("COŽE!?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Button button1 ,button2;

    @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                 button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        button1.setText("xyz");
                    }
                });
     button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        button2.setText("abc");
                    }
                });
    }
```