# Is there a way to stop MouseListener?

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

Okay, so what I'm trying to do is place an image by clicking. I have a boolean and I have it set so that it's true when the mouse is being pressed, and false when it's released. Then I have the following codes:

```
if (place == true){
                msex = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                msey = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
            }
```

and this on the main screen so it shows up:

```
if (place == true){
            d.drawImage(twilightblock,msex - 45,msey - 85,this);
        }
```

However, when I try it, I click and it shows up, but it disappears when I release the mouse button. It also moves around with the mouse instead of staying in one place. I'm wondering, is there a way to stop MouseListener in the middle, like, right after the button is pressed? If so, that would be perfect. :D

Comment: What event are you listening too? Might be a matter of just using a different event.

Comment: Also, seems like the behavior that you are seeing is similar to drag-and-drop. And, what you really want is to: select an image by clicking on it and then select a destination with another click, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a MouseAdapter and select the appropriate methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html

1. onClick on the image (the first component)
2. store the image's data or reference in a temporary structure/object
3. onCLick on a second component
4. access the image's data from the tempprary structure/object and apply it to the second component
5. delete the image from the first component

Answering your comment, this is a high level scaffold of what you could do:

```
public static void main() {
    SomeOtherObject so; // use to store app data
    // create possibly many components of type B
    JComponentB compB = new JComponentB(so);
    JComponentA compA = new JComponentA(so);
    // add them to your JFrame, or other component
}

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
class JComponentA  extends MouseAdapter {
    String imagePath;
    Image myImage;

    public JComponentA(SomeOtherObject so) { };

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.imagePath = so.getImagePath;
        // display new image, or maybe swap images
    }
}

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
class JComponentB extends MouseAdapter {
    String imagePath;
    Image myImage;

    public JComponentB(SomeOtherObject so) { };

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        so.setImagePath(this.imagePath);
        // delete image, or maybe do a swap (that requires two strings in SomeOtherObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying to use onClick, but OnClickListener is apparently only for Android, and I'm not programming for android. Is there an alternative? Also, how would I save and access the data from a structure/object? I'm really new to this....

Comment: But when I try to implement it, is says it cannot be resolved to a type. And then I tried to figure out what was wrong, and every thread was about androids .-. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606662/onclicklistener-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-and-not-applicable
I can't import anything it only lets me create an interface. Is that what I need to do?

Comment: I recommend that you use an IDE, it will help you with such details. Either Netbeans or Eclipse are good options. You need to import the MouseAdapter class. I have added it to the code snippet.

Comment: Check out class inheritance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html