# The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the
>        type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button new_claim_button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new_claim_button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        new_claim_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            }
            });
    }
}
```

Please ignore functionality. It does not do much, but I need to figure out what is causing the error before I can continue.

Comment: The error is misleading. You haven't implemented the `OnClickListener` interface's method.

Comment: Your opening and closing brackets don't match up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type and not applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606662/onclicklistener-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-and-not-applicable)

Answer (score 5):

As the comments say, your brackets don't match, and you're missing method implementation. Correct listener should override onClick(), as below:

```
new_claim_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //implementation    
    }        
});
```

Comment: I did what you said and added the override. The error is gone, but it still crashes when I try and test it.  it wont even open the app.

Comment: There are so many possible reasons, that without logcat error, possibly AndroidManifest and more code it's guesswork. Post a new question.